# parse pdf with pdfminer could not get the text but cid instead

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I want to parse pdf files with pdfminer, with most of the pdf files I get the text successfully，but with the others i only get the cids not the truly text. The output is like this:

```
2016 (cid:411) 1 (cid:579) 1 (cid:556)(cid:851) 2016 (cid:411) 12 (cid:579) 31 (cid:556) (cid:512)(cid:1) (cid:226)(cid:99)(cid:1054)(cid:971)(cid:174)(cid:834)(cid:97)(cid:62)(cid:844)(cid:114)(cid:580)(cid:1044)(cid:166)(cid:261)(cid:166)(cid:261)(cid:779)(cid:770)(cid:1)...
```

I also tried the commands:

```
python tools/conv_cmap.py pdfminer/cmap Adobe-CNS1 cmaprsrc/cid2code_Adobe_CNS1.txt
python tools/conv_cmap.py pdfminer/cmap Adobe-GB1 cmaprsrc/cid2code_Adobe_GB1.txt
```

Does not work.

The failed pdf file link:
http://www.neeq.com.cn/disclosure/2017/2017-01-16/1484566464_337129.pdf

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add more tag like "python" to your question. It'll help to reach relevant users.